# How to sort table on click jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a table on JSP page. I want to sort it, when click button. How I should do it? Result table will on other jsp page or I can change current table? 
That is my servlet, but I cant understand, how return result after sorting. It 
Thank you!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/home")
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String[] name = {"x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6","x7","x8","x9","x10"};
    int[] price = {7600,8500,11700,15000,6000,10200,6400,5800,8700,10400};
    int[] memory = {4,4,12,16,2,10,3,1,6,8};
    int[] camera = {10,8,10,15,6,9,5,4,8,12};


    public HomeServlet() {
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int temp = 0;


        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

        while(temp!=price.length-1){
            Product pr = new Product(name[temp], camera[temp], memory[temp], price[temp]);
            temp++;
            products.add(pr);
        }

        request.setAttribute("productList", products);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

        if (request.getParameter("button1") != null) {

             Sorts.function1(price);// in this function I sort table by a certain field

             } else if (request.getParameter("button2") != null) {

             Sorts.function1(memory);

             }
    }
//????  WHAT I SHOULD DO HERE?

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you already loaded data and there is a table in JSP. I think it is better to sort a table in client side rather doing in servlet and return back again to client.

Comment: Ok, how I can do it?

Comment: Simply use JavaScript